# Can using same tracking number trigger two instances of Google Analytics page view count?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

If you write the same Gtag code with the same ID twice, can it trigger 2 page views in Google Analytics, or does Google filter for these double cases?

So would it be possible to artificially increase your page view count?

Answer (score 1):

So to test this, I added the code using the tag method and the legacy code on one page and hit a page refresh.

I had 1 session, 1 user and 2 pageviews. The first pageview has zero seconds on site, the second one is the actual pageview.

The problem this creates is that due to the first pageview being counted as a non-bounce pageview, your bounce rate goes down drastically.

TO answer your question, this can be used to hike up your pageviews. However, sessions and users remain unchanged.